# Foreign key doesn't keep data consistency

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

Many days ago I made a database which had two tables:

- member(member_id(PK),name)
- account(account_id(PK),member_id(FK),amount).

So Normally I cant `DELETE` any member if member have balance in account table . Before it was work well.
But today I import same script and I can delete a member even member  have balance in account table.

I don't know what happends? I don't remember previous server version of mysql. Now I am running `mysql 5.5.16` and MySQL client version is `mysqlnd 5.0.8-dev - 20102224 - Revision: 310735  in localhost`.

my code is

```
//account table
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `account` (
   `account_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `member_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `dates` date NOT NULL,
   `amount` float NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`account_id`),
   KEY `FK_account_1` (`member_id`)
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

//member table
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `member` (
  `member_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `account_num` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`member_id`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=34 ;

//and this code
ALTER TABLE `account`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_account_1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`member_id`) 
    REFERENCES `member`(`member_id`) 
    ON DELETE CASCADE 
    ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Comment: Please edit your question and show the complete **CREATE TABLE** statements for both tables.

Comment: ok I am edtiting my question

Comment: Are you sure that this prevented you from deleting rows in `member` that had values for that member in `account`?  There is no such constraint in your DDL.

Comment: your code works, see this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/34769/1 uncomment the DELETE sequence and see the different result.

Comment: yes I am sure , I delete many member which have account. but only show consistency behavior when I am trying to truncate

Comment: i don't understand your previous comment. As well as most part of your post, I think you should clarify since we maybe don't understand what you want

Comment: I want member cant be delete if member have account balance. are you understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand this well but:

The constraint you have means that every time you delete a member, the member will be deleted together with any balance it has in the account table. (`ON DELETE CASCADE`)

If this is not your desired behavior, and you want mysql to raise an exception when deleting a member that has a balance; then **just remove the** `ON DELETE CASCADE` **line from your constraint definition**.

Comment: Thank you very much. I find my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE account
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_account_member` 
FOREIGN KEY (`member_id`)
REFERENCES `member` (`member_id`)
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Comment: That's why I asked you to post your code; Michael answered before knowing you were already doing this.

Comment: please ask me, whats problem